# Sharepoint Search Service Administration - Get System Status with Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

is it possible to read the system status of a Sharepoint (2019) SSA with powershell?
I am especially interested in the values:
Recent crawl rate
Searchable items
and Recent query rate

[Search Service Administration - System Status - Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yNLi.jpg)

Unfortunately I do not get on with this problem. many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
($ssa.GetType().InvokeMember("get_Monitoring",("NonPublic", "Instance", "InvokeMethod"),$null,$ssa,$null))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So now I have got the query rate and crawl rate. :)
Important is also the value "Searchable Items".
Can you help me here too?